# Требуется помощь в выборе языка программирования

Tags: java, машинное-обучение

Допустим мне нужно написать компьютерную программу с сложным алгоритмом, который будет работать с огромным объемом информации и еще туда придется впихнуть машинное обучение. Чтобы вам было легче понять о чем я говорю, приведу в пример уже существующую программу: Наса или кто другой написали программу для нахождения планет потенциально пригодных для жизни. Они показывают их программе спектры и другую собранную информацию о планете Х. Далее компьютер опираясь на уже известные данные о других планетах может выдвенуть теорию пригодна ли эта планета Х для жизни или нет. На каком языке пишут такие программы? Подойдет ли Java? Заранее спасибо:)

Comment: питон больше для анализа и машиноого обучения

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подобные как у NASA программы пишутся на на `C` - `C++`.

Отрывок из [статьи](https://tproger.ru/articles/nasa-programming-language/) с tproger:

> Длинный (и более интересный) ответ от инсайдера:
>
> И хотя каждый может
>   писать на том, на чем ему удобно, большинство используют C, много
>   меньше работников пишут на C++ и уж совсем мало — на Java. Абсолютное
>   меньшинство используют ADA, Fortran и Lisp. Assembler используется,
>   когда речь идет о необходимости оптимизации или драйвере. Для
>   моделирования, как минимум в JPL, большинство поддерживают MatLab, но
>   есть и те, кто используют Mathematica (подозреваю, что кто-то
>   пользуется даже Maple, но лично я таких людей еще не встречал). В
>   целом, ни в каком проекте даже среднего масштаба не используются
>   скриптовые языки, и уж тем более, Python, Ruby, Perl и другие, потому
>   что эти проекты должны удовлетворять некоторым требованиям.
>
> Приверженность C не лишена смысла. Все крупные проекты организации
>   обязательно пишутся на C. Например, код для марсоходов написан на C с
>   единственным исключением в виде Gestalt, программного обеспечения для
>   визуальной навигации, написанном на C++. Конечно, не лишена смысла и
>   разработка ПО на другом языке, но при этом этот код должен быть легко
>   портируем на основной язык. На нем же написаны и драйвера для всего
>   коммерческого оборудования. С быстрый, для него существует множество
>   качественных библиотек, он позволяет писать на очень низком уровне,
>   «ближе к железу», что очень полезно. Огромным плюсом является и то,
>   что есть много компиляторов, которые придерживаются стандарта C.
>   Например, если вы пользуетесь, gcc, то в силу строгости правил
>   генерации кода, вы можете быть уверены, что программа будет
>   выполняться одинаково на абсолютном большинстве машин. О других языках
>   нельзя сказать того же. В частности, я не берусь утверждать, что мало
>   компиляторов C++ поддерживают стандарт языка, но несколько лет назад
>   это было именно так.

Не думаю, что вы будете писать такие программы, как у NASA. Скорее всего, для ваших целей подойдет Java.

Про машинное обучение -  для Java есть куча хороших библиотек, в том числе и от Microsoft, Google, Bing(вроде) по ML.

Про содействие двух программ(когда одна передает данные другой) - Java для этого отлично подходит, т.к. она отлично подходит для работ с БД. Для Java есть хорошие фраемворки для работы с БД. Одна программа записывает данные в БД, другая их берет из БД.